# More than 1 question in a thread

Tags: discussion

Is it bad practice to ask more than $1$ question in a MO post, like [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285160/order-preserving-surjective-map-f-cal-p-omega-fin-to-0-1)?

Comment: Or here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313516/a-shelah-group-in-zfc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be bad practice.  It can also be good practice.

In the proffered example, the questions are brief enough and related enough that I have no strong objection to it.  If you have a larger theme (maps from A with property P), and have a purpose in asking multiple questions with different ranges (knowing how it looks on B says one thing, while knowing how it looks on C tells another), it might be good to add a link to the 'mother question' which states the theme clearly.  If you are in search of a mother theme, that (along with guesses as to what such a theme looks like) could serve as motivation.

If you have a larger goal (larger than just getting answers to the two questions), I can only see adding it as an improvement.

Gerhard "Tell Us What You're Thinking" Paseman, 2017.11.03.